# Reduce space between header and table view cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, tableview, space

I have table view with custom header and a cell with single section.
I want to reduce the space between the header and the 1st cell.
I have used heightforrow method as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView == tableview1
        {
            return 1
        }
        else
        {
            return 0
        }
    }
```

This did not have any effect on the spacing.
The height of the header is 774.The cell starts from 798 and it is grayed out as shown in the image.
[image]

How to reduce the space of it which is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude instead of zero

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView == tableview1
    {
        return CGFloat(Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude)
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: this 1 didnt help.i want for tableview1 only

Comment: updated my answer, if not resolved can u share your height for row at index path delegate method

Comment: i have not used that delegate method